# JSDoc typings for typescript for JavaScript reducer accumulator

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I am trying to type the accumulator in a JavaScript `reducer` using JSDocs but cannot work out how to do this.

I've tried typing it inline at initialization but that didn't work. Any hints or ideas? Here's the sample code. It's complaining about param passed to arr.push():

```
/**
* @type {Array<String>}
*/
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

/**
 * @type {Array<Array>}
 */
const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if(item.length % 3 === 0) {
     // [ts] Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to
     // parameter of type 'never'.
     acc.push([item, item.length]);
   }
   return acc;
}, []);
```

Here's the GitHub repo which has the `tsconfig.json` file in the root of the project for the tsc settings: https://github.com/guyellis/typescript-as-a-linter

And here's the file in that repo from which I took the code above: https://github.com/guyellis/typescript-as-a-linter/blob/master/lib/reducer.js

Comment: BTW why are you using `reduce` instead of what appear to be a job for `map`? `const result = arr.map(item => [item, item.length]);`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - good question. It's a really bad example! I should have provided an example that produced a larger or smaller array instead of something that should use `map()`.

Comment: I edit the question to make the example a bit more realistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty array you are passing as the initial state gets the type `never[]`.  See [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9976) for more background.  To avoid that, you can put it in a constant and give the constant a type:

```
/**
* @type {Array<String>}
*/
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

/** @type {Array<[string, number]>} */
const init = [];

/**
 * @type {Array<[string, number]>}
 */
const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc.push([item, item.length]);
   return acc;
}, init);
```

Comment: Thanks @matt-mccutchen - If nobody else comes up with a way to type this inline or some other way without adding an explicitly declared initializer then I'll tag this as the accepted answer in a couple of days.

Comment: Now it's possible to cast any expression inline with the [Cast syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts).

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param {Pose['parameterValues']} values
 * @param {Pose['variants']} variants
*/
function getSrc (values, variants) {
  return values.reduce(
    /** @param {{[key: string]:Array<string>}} paths */
    (paths, { camera, light }, index) => {
      paths[light.name] = []
      for (let c = camera.start; c < camera.end; c += camera.increment) {
        paths[light.name].push(
          variants[index].replace('light', light.value).replace('camera', String(c))
        )
      }
      return paths
    }, {})
}
```